# Is there a keyboard shortcut to right click on the Windows button (on Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I would need (for a Python program) **a keyboard shortcut to right click on the Windows button** (on Windows 10).

The right click on the Windows button brings out a context menu including Run, Search, File Explorer, Task Manager etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut for Start button's context menu is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, exactly! What a mistake, I corrected my post now. Thank you!